# DetailsView - Values not changing in ItemUpdating

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have DetailsView binded to one object. When `ItemUpdating` is called (when I click update) `OldValues` is empty and `NewValues` contains old values (are the same as before update).

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="CustomerDetailsView" runat="server"
    DefaultMode="Edit"
    AutoGenerateRows="false"
    OnItemUpdating="CustomerDetailsView_ItemUpdating"
    >
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last name" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First name" ReadOnly="True" />
        <%-- Other fields ... --%>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Code behind:

```
private Customer customer;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var context = new CustomersContext())
    {
        customer = context.Logins.First();
    }

    CustomerDetailsView.DataSource = new List<Customer>() { customer };
    CustomerDetailsView.DataBind();
}

protected void CustomerDetailsView_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // e.OldValues.Count == 0
    // e.NewValues["FirstName"] - is same as taken from database
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, I was setting new DataSource every time the page was reloaded even if it was post-back.

Should be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        using (var context = new CustomersContext())
        {
            customer = context.Logins.First();
        }

        CustomerDetailsView.DataSource = new List<Customer>() { customer };
        CustomerDetailsView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Can't see OldValues but NewValues looks correct.

Answer (score 2):

See this answer: [OldValues collection in event "ItemUpdating" of DetailsView is always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177876/oldvalues-collection-in-event-itemupdating-of-detailsview-is-always-empty)

It appears that this only works if you use the DataSourceID property bound to a data source control.

Comment: He writes that "NewValues are ok" these are values I care most. I would rather not use datasource control, and I don't much care about OldValues.